# Can I use my own Amazon Affiliate link in a blog post?

Tags: discussion, blog, amazon

Wondering if there's any policy on this, or if SA has a particular stance on it. If I do a equipment review for the blog, I'll link to the Amazon page for the product. Is it ok to use an affiliate link, where I personally could profit if people buy the product? I think any actual revenue would be minuscule, I'm more interested in doing it just so I could see some data on click through / purchase.

What do y'all think?

Answer (score 1):

The answer back from SE was "please don't".